# Refresh Program Window

Tags: vbscript, batch-file

We have a program that needs to have its contents refreshed every couple of minutes. The program does it automatically, but only if the program window is selected, which is no use if we are using other programs.

Is there a way with some batch file scripting or vb scripting even to refresh an active window in Windows XP?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: May be a silly question, but if you're not using the program, why would you want it to keep refreshing? It sounds like it's only refreshing when the window is active and it's probably by design. Also, what do you mean by refresh? Does the user hit a button, or is it done automatically (I'm assuming it's refreshing from a database or a webpage or something)?

Comment: you may use the time ticker that will call to refresh the contents of your system everytime the ticker ticks for a minute of time.

Comment: It is an open window in a program we use to monitor if any important jobs come into the call logging system we use. If any category 1 or 2 calls come in, we need to know about them asap. But we are using other programs during the day for IT support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's the [AppActivate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wzcddbek%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) method on the [WshShellObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ahcz2kh6%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) class.
Combine that with the `Sleep` function and a loop and you might have what you need.

Something like this might work:

```
Set shell = Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
While 1 = 1
  shell.AppActivate("The app title or the process id")
  Wscript.Sleep(60000) ' in milliseconds, so this is one minute
Wend
```